# General characteristics of a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

If the normal distribution curve is symmetrical about the vertical line then the

`mean = mode = median`

This would mean that:

```
Prob( X < mean) = Prob( X > mean) = .....
```

What is the missing part of this concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally for continuous probability distributions that are symmetric about their median, if they have a mean at all, then the probability of being greater than the mean and the probability of being less than the mean are both equal to $1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since

> Prob(X < mean) + Prob (X = mean) + Prob (X > mean)=1
>
> and Prob(X = mean)=0   (continuous distribution)

You get

> Prob(X < mean) = Prob (X > mean)=0.5

Comment: You might need something like: " for a continuous distribution $\Pr(X = \text{mean})=0$".

Comment: I added that to the answer above,thanks.